# NX Unable to complete project graph creation. Worker stopped with exit code: 1

Tags: angular, typescript, nomachine-nx

I have an Angular project and I am using `nx`. When I run `npm install` I get this error:

```
 >  NX   Nx Daemon was not able to compute the project graph.

   Log file with the error: ...\node_modules\.cache\nx\d\daemon-error.log
   Please file an issue at https://github.com/nrwl/nx
   Nx Daemon is going to be disabled until you run "nx reset"..

 >  NX   Unable to complete project graph creation. Worker stopped with exit code: 1
```

I also checked the log file:

```
'Error detected when creating a project graph: Unable to complete
   project graph creation. Worker stopped with exit code: 1'
   
 Error detected when creating a project graph: Cannot find module
   '...\node_modules\nx\src\project-graph\project-graph-worker.js'
```

Any idea?

Comment: at least you should try to read `\node_modules\.cache\nx\d\daemon-error.log` most likely there is something meaningfull there

Comment: @Andrei I already checked it. `Error detected when creating a project graph: Cannot find module
   '...\node_modules\nx\src\project-graph\project-graph-worker.js'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem by updating the node version to `v14.17.1`. It is good idea to create an `nx` workspace (`npx create-nx-workspace@latest`) to make sure that your system requirements is OK with `nx`, then try to run `npm install` in your Angular project.

Other things that might be helpful:

```
 1. remove the `node_modules`
 2. npm cache verify
 3. npm install -g @nrwl/cli
 4. npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution did not work for me, so after some digging I found this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8796#issuecomment-1063435852) and disabled the daemon by running:

```bash
export NX_DAEMON=false; <your build command here>
```